# How to normalize facial landmark coordinates for reconstruction

Tags: python, numpy, dlib

I'm using dlib to detect facial landmark coordinates in several video frames. How can I normalize these coordinates in a way that makes it easy to convert back to their original coordinates without having to save any extra data?

Here is an example with python and numpy:

```
def process_keypoints(keypoints):
    # Need to save center variable to correctly go from normalized keypoints to original keypoints
    center = np.mean(keypoints, axis=0)
    keypoints_norm = keypoints - center
    return keypoints_norm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save extra data but you are fine with some extra compute afterwards try

```
#replace the first point with the center
keypoints_norm[0] = center
return key_points_norm

#reconstruct
center = keypoints_norm[0]
keyporints_norm[0]=-np.sum(keypoints_norm[1:])
```